# Image within circle object causes pixelation d3 js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

It appears I've followed the steps properly to fill a circle with an external image.  I've tried numerous different image links, yet still can't resolve this pixelation issue.  Any help is appreciated, here's a link to my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/SdN2F/7/

Code issue snipet:

```
var photoCircle = d3.select('svg')
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", width-160)
                .attr("cy", height-140)
                .attr("r", radius-35)
                .style("fill", "url(#photo)");

var image = d3.select('svg')
                .append("pattern")
                .attr("id", "photo")
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("width", width-160)
                .attr("height", height-140)    
                .append("image")
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("width", width-160)
                .attr("height", height-140)
                .attr("xlink:href", "http://static-1.nexusmods.com/15/mods/110/images/50622-1-1391287636.jpeg");
```

Comment: Well you have to set the size of the pattern (i.e. image) appropriately (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/SdN2F/8/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `patternUnits` attribute of `pattern`.

```
var image = d3.select('svg').append('defs')
                .append("pattern")
                .attr("id", "photo")
                .attr("patternUnits","userSpaceOnUse")
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("width", 2*radius)
                .attr("height", 2*radius)

.append("image")
                 .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("width", 2*radius)
                .attr("height", 2*radius)
                .attr("xlink:href", "http://static-1.nexusmods.com/15/mods/110/images/50622-1-1391287636.jpeg");
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/SdN2F/11/

Comment: yep, I saw that after I posted the answer :)